# Problem in scraping link(href) using selenium; href="#"

Tags: python, selenium, href

I'm a amateur at using python, and I'm trying to scrape the url from the html below using selenium.

```
<a class="" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #1b1b1b;" onclick="toDetailOrUrl(event, '1641438','')">[안내] 빗썸 - 빗썸 글로벌 간 간편 가상자산 이동 서비스 종료 안내</a>
```

In ordinary case, the link url i want to get is in just beside 'href=', but there is just "#" in that html.

When i run the code below that is usual way to using selenium to scrape the given html, it returns a https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43. But is just what i entered in 'driver.get()', and i don't want.

```
   url = "https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43"
    driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    bo =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[1]/tr[@style='cursor:pointer;border-top:1px solid #dee2e6;background-color: white']/td[2]/a")
    print(bo.get_attribute('href'))
```

What i want is https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/board-contents/1641438. You can get this url when you click a item corresponding with the xpath i wrote above.

I want this url using selenium or other programmatic ways, no need to open a chrome and enter the url in addressbar, and click using mouse... like that.

good

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
bo.click()
```

in order to click the element you want (I assumed you want to click bo)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].getAttribute("href")',bo))
```

selenium , bo.get_attribute('href') is actually doing document.getElementById("somelocaator").href which returns full href , as '#' indicates current page you get current URL you provided in get()

If you just need # you can use the execute_script